# ui router resolve is throwing error provider not found

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have got a ui -router state here

```
 var AccountParentState = {
            url: "/Account",
            views: accountrootview,
            stickA: true,
        },
            AccountAddState = {
                url: "/add",
                views: addaccountview,
                controller: "account-controller",
                resolve: {
                    Name: function () {
                        return "Joydeep";
                    }
                }
            };

        $stateProvider
            .state('account', AccountParentState)
            .state("account.add", AccountAddState)
```

And this is my controller :

```
angular.module('ngApp').controller('account-controller', ['$scope', '$state', "account", "plugin-factory", "Name", function ($scope
    , $state
    , account
    , plugins, Name) {

    console.log(Name);


}]);
```

When I am trying to resolve the `Name` within the `account-controller` . Its throwing the error as :

```
Unknown provider: NameProvider <- Name <- account-controller
```

My question is how to resolve this situation . Or resolve the data within the ui-router state using `resolve` property .

Comment: Such error mostly comes when you have a `ng-controller='account-controller'` somewhere in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help you to see the issue, I [created working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rIOrc31Crd62p5SC5cef?p=preview), which does use similar definition to the above states:

```
  var AccountParentState = {
    url: "/Account",
    views: { '' : 
       { template: 'Account state <hr/><div ui-view=""></div>',} },
    stickA: true, 
  },
    AccountAddState = {
      url: "/add",
      //views: addaccountview,
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      controller: "account-controller",
      resolve: {
        Name: function() {
          return "Joydeep";
        }
      }
    };

  $stateProvider
    .state('account', AccountParentState)
    .state("account.add", AccountAddState)
```

Factories and controller:

```
  .factory('account', function(){return {}})
  .factory('plugin-factory', function(){return {}})
  .controller('account-controller', 
     ['$scope', '$state', "account", "plugin-factory", "Name"
     , function($scope, $state, account, plugins, Name) {    
       console.log(Name);
     }
  ])
```

And that is working, because controller was instantiated by the `UI-Router`, as a part of the state transition.

If, on the other hand, we will extend that example with this (see [forked broken version](http://plnkr.co/edit/yaOUNhzRK2ci2I8vQAyA?p=preview)) line in the index.html (outside of the state def)

```
<div ng-controller="account-controller"></div>
<div ui-view=""></div>
```

The issue will appear. Why? Because now the controller is **not** managed by the `UI-Router`. It is not injected by its infrastructure, not provided with configured value `'Name'`. It is "plain angular" style..

Check the working solution [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/rIOrc31Crd62p5SC5cef?p=preview) and the broken [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yaOUNhzRK2ci2I8vQAyA?p=preview)

Comment: my html doesn't contain ng-controller . Its solely through the ui-router

Comment: That's why I created the plunker. You can observe the working version and compare with your solution. My is working, so you should be easily able to find out the difference. From my experience, the best way how to find out the issue, is to be able to compare with working stuff ;) Hope it helps... enjoy UI-Router

Comment: Kohler . It wasn't the issue actually . But yes your plunker helped me out the contextual resolve object to resolve within the state ref .

Comment: Great to see that, Joy, really. Enjoy amazing tool, `UI-Router` ;)